# Unable to set an array with useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to set an array to a state hook. Basically I want to keep a track of a per-row (of grid sort of) Edit Dialog Open State. Basically per row, I have a Edit button, launches a . As all seems rendered initially, I am trying to manage the  show hide by keeping an array in the parent grid component. When user clicks on the Edit button, per row, I want to pass the rowData as props.data and want to provide the Edit functionality.

To keep the state of the editDialogs (show/hide), I am making a array of objects useState hook as follows:

```
  const [editDialogsModalState, setEditDialogsModalState] = useState([{}]); // every edit dialog has it's own state
     ...
 function initializeEditDialogsModalState(dataSet) {
    let newState = [];
    dataSet.map((item) => newState.push({ id: item.id, state: false }));
    return setEditDialogsModalState(newState);  // **PROBLEM->Not setting**
  }

function addUDButtons(currentRowDataMovie) {  // my edit/delete button UI code
    const currRowDataId = currentRowDataMovie.id;
    return (
      <span>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-info"
          onClick={() => setEditDialogsState(currRowDataId)}
        >
          Edit
        </button>
        {editDialogsModalState[currRowDataId].state && ( // **PROBLEM->null data even after set call**
          <EditMovieComponent
            open={editDialogsModalState[currRowDataId].state}
            onToggle={toggleEditDialogsModalState(currentRowDataMovie)}
            movie={currentRowDataMovie}
          />
        )}
}
     ......
function buildGrid() {
    {
      if (!ready) {
        // data is not there, why to build the grid
        return;
    }
      initializeEditDialogsModalState(movies);
             ...........
}
```

However not able to get the editStates. A screen shot from debugger where I can see the movies (REST output), ready, but not the editDialogsModalState state array.

[image]

In general, is there a better ways of implementing such per-row basis functionality where on click of a button I want to open a React-bootstrap  and pass the row-specific dataitem for doing operations ? (I am learning React, so may not not yet fully aware of all pointers).

Thanks,
Pradip

Comment: I think you don't need to use `return` here `return setEditDialogsModalState(newState);`

Comment: I tried that also, did not help.
`code`
function initializeEditDialogsModalState(dataSet) {
    let newState = [];
    dataSet.map((item) => newState.push({ id: item.id, state: false }));
    setEditDialogsModalState(newState);
  }
`code`

Comment: Did you check to see if your program is reaching the setEditDialogsModalState call?

Comment: Yes @RaoVirinchi that is going there. I have checked that.

Comment: Could you post the full code please? Is this hole thing a big component or do you have it as multiple components?

You dont need that return before setEditDialogsModalState also you should use forEach instead if map to loop the dataset.

Is setEditDialogsState supposed to be the same as setEditDialogsModalState?